# Pandas error when creating DataFrame from MS SQL Server database: 'ODBC SQL type -151 is not yet supported

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas

I'm trying to create a DataFrame from a table in MS SQL Server 2016, I have used the sample database AdventureWorks2012, and here is the code:

```
import pyodbc 
cnxn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};"
                      "Server=localhost;"
                      "Database=AdventureWorks2012;"
                      "Trusted_Connection=yes;")


cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM HumanResources.Employee')

df = pandas.read_sql(sql, cnxn)
cursor.close()
cnxn.close()
```

but I get an error:

----> 1 df = pandas.read_sql(sql, cnxn)

ProgrammingError: ('ODBC SQL type -151 is not yet supported.  column-index=3  type=-151', 'HY106')

Comment: Try upgrading your pyodbc and pandas versions both.

Comment: both freshly installed a few minutes before asking the question. But the error is pointing to the dataframe creation line, why is it about ODBC?

Comment: I got this error when I had a type in MSSQL that wasn't supported by the driver. If I remember, the format was a DateTimeOffset datatype. You would have to do a type conversion in your query when querying. Otherwise, you could also wait when the MSSQL ODBC driver gets updated.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this has started a bit showing the direction, but I'm not there yet. You mentioned you had a problem with data type. So I checked by importing only some fields, and date and time are not a problem BUT I found the trouble-making field, it has data type "hierarchyID", That's the one that generates the error. How can I convert that thing to just a string on import?

Comment: @MCGCode You would have to cast the field to a string in your select query (e.g. `SELECT CAST(myField AS NVARCHAR(4000)), ...`)

Answer (score 7):

So I'll just create my answer since I now know the complete context of your problem. The issue is related to ODBC driver compatibility issues with the new MS SQL Server 2016. You mentioned that you were able to whittle down your fields to one that had a data type of **hierarchyid**. Based on the documentation presented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/hierarchyid-data-type-method-reference), you can convert it to a `nvarchar(4000)` string representation. Thus, your solution would be in how you write your query.

Where you have your code currently as:

```
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM HumanResources.Employee')
```

I would modify it to:

```
cursor.execute("""
SELECT CAST(theHierarchyIdField AS NVARCHAR(4000)) AS myConvertedField
    ,additionalField
    ,...
FROM HumanResources.Employee
""")
```

I can understand that it would be annoying to explicitly write all the fields in the query that you want to pull, but it's the only way to do the conversion on the SQL side before pulling it into Python as a recognizable data type.

Another solution would be to redesign your table schema and alter the `hierarchyid` type to `nvarchar(4000)`, but I don't know if you have the rights to alter the table so I'll just propose the above solution.

Also, if you're planning to use `pandas` to pull in the data, then just set your `sql` variable to the query string and `read_sql`:

```
sql = """
SELECT CAST(theHierarchyIdField AS NVARCHAR(4000)) AS myConvertedField
    ,additionalField
    ,...
FROM HumanResources.Employee
"""

df = pandas.read_sql(sql, cnxn)
```

Answer (score 7):

If you have no use of the columns with ODBC type -151 (TSQL [hierarchid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/hierarchyid-data-type-method-reference?view=sql-server-ver15)), you can simply add a data type handler on the connection which converts it to a string:

```
    def HandleHierarchyId(v):
      return str(v)

    conn = pyodbc.connect(connection_string)
    conn.add_output_converter(-151, HandleHierarchyId)
```

You can also use any other method listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/hierarchyid-data-type-method-reference?view=sql-server-ver15#data-type-conversion) to convert this type.

Comment: This should be the chosen answer. Thanks!